# Understanding stack-allocated objects deallocation

Tags: c, arrays, memory-management

I'm trying to understand how deallocation of stack-allocated objects behaves. To be precise, I'm trying to find an explanation in the standard ([N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)). Consider the following simple function:

```
void foo(){
    char test[4096];
    test[10] = 0;
}
```

Here the `test` array will be deallocated when `foo` exits. It is easy to see in `objdump` that `test` is allocated on the stack. The standard (emphasis mine) states:

> An object whose identifier is declared with no linkage and without the
>   storage-class specifier static has ***automatic storage duration***, as do
>   some compound literals.

So `test` has automatic storage duration. We can easily rewrite the function as follows:

```
void test(){
    char *test= malloc(4096 * sizeof(char));
    test[10] = 0;
    free(test);
}
```

But we have to deallocate it by ourselves, and yet `test` still has ***automatic storage duration***.

***QUESTION:*** How the standard specifies that `char test[4096]` will be deallocated on function exit? The standard ***does not*** state that `test` is allocated on the stack, it is implementation defined.

Comment: The standard doesn't specify that it gets deallocated, only that the memory turns invalid.

Comment: In the second case you're allocating a **pointer to char** not the memory of your array. Arrays and pointers **aren't the same thing**. So the only variable with automatic storage in your case is the pointer `test`, that will be deallocated at function exit. The memory allocated by `malloc` is taken from heap and is permanent memory (until not explicetly deallocated).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The standard describes the various storage durations at [§6.2.4](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.4)

> 1 An object has a storage duration that determines its lifetime. There
>   are four storage durations: static, thread, automatic, and allocated.
>   Allocated storage is described in 7.22.3.
>
> 2 The lifetime of an object is the portion of program execution during
>   which storage is guaranteed to be reserved for it. An object exists,
>   has a constant address, and retains its last-stored value
>   throughout its lifetime. If an object is referred to outside of its
>   lifetime, the behavior is undefined. The value of a pointer becomes
>   indeterminate when the object it points to (or just past) reaches the
>   end of its lifetime.
>
> 6 For such an object that does not have a variable length array type,
>   its lifetime extends from entry into the block with which it is
>   associated until execution of that block ends in any way. (Entering an
>   enclosed block or calling a function suspends, but does not end,
>   execution of the current block.) If the block is entered recursively,
>   a new instance of the object is created each time. The initial value
>   of the object is indeterminate. If an initialization is specified for
>   the object, it is performed each time the declaration or compound
>   literal is reached in the execution of the block; otherwise, the value
>   becomes indeterminate each time the declaration is reached.

So you are pretty much correct. It doesn't at all describe when and how storage is deallocated per se. It only specifies when that storage is accessible with well-defined semantics. An implementation need not deallocate the storage of a variable with automatic storage duration right away, you just can't touch it if you want your program to be standard compliant.

For allocated storage the same goes, with the added caveat that you have to explicitly tell the implementation you are done with the storage. But even if you do "free" it, an implementation may hold on to it still for a while longer.

It's possible on paper for a very poor implementation to exist, one which never deallocates memory. But in practice, those are culled naturally because poor implementations of C just become disused by the masses, and abandoned.

Comment: So it mean I was wrong about my second example. `test` has allocated storage duration there, right?

Comment: @St.Antario - Not `test`, but `*test`. The pointer has automatic storage duration. The *pointee* has allocated duration. It may seem like splitting hairs, but an important distinction.

Answer (score 1):

This is about the lifetime of the *allocated memory* returned from the allocator function(s). For the memory allocator functions, it is stated explicitly that (Quoting from `C11`, chapter §7.22.3.1, emphasis mine)

> [...] The
>   pointer returned if the allocation succeeds is suitably aligned so that it may be assigned to
>   a pointer to any type of object with a fundamental alignment requirement and then used
>   to access such an object or an array of such objects **in the space allocated (until the space
>   is explicitly deallocated). The lifetime of an allocated object extends from the allocation
>   until the deallocation.** [...]

So, you need to deallocate the allocated memory explicitly. Unless you deallocate explicitly, the memory allocated remains *valid* to be used (and subsequently cause a [memory leak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak), if not handled properly).

OTOH, in the second snippet, the variable `test` is still goes out of scope on the function exit, as it has automatic storage. The memory allocated **for** the variable `test` (note: not the memory pointed to by `test`) is not valid anymore, and attempt to access that would be undefined behaviour. Remember, this is true for the variable `test`, i.e., after the function returns, `&test` becomes invalid, however, since the memory pointed by `test` was allocated through an allocator function, returning that pointer and using it from the function call would still be a valid access.

Quoting the spec again,

> [...] If an object is referred to outside of its
>   lifetime, the behavior is undefined. [...]

Answer (score 1):

The `test` variable in your first example **is an array of 4096 bytes.**

The `test` in your second example **is just a pointer variable (4/8 bytes)** that *you initialize with the pointer value obtained from `malloc(3)` from the heap space.*

Both `test` variables (4096 and 4/8 bytes, resp.) **are indeed deallocated automatically when your program leaves the routine,** but you have allocated 4096 bytes extra in your second example, from the heap, of which C language has no idea (they were allocated in a library routine that has nothing special, and so they don't return automatically to the heap if you don't do that explicitly. ---the heap is a special memory place, known to malloc(), that allows you to get extra memory in any order, and returnable also in any order---)